# Fix the position of the axes label

Tags: labeling

How can I set the position of the axes labels (X,Y,Z), so that, among other things, they do not overlap with the numbers in the axes? Here an easy example:

```
a={{1,1,0.3},{1,2,0.4},{1,3,0.5},{2,1,0.6},{2,2,0.7},{2,3,0.8}};

b=ListPlot3D[a,
PlotLabel->Style["A",15],
LabelStyle->Directive[Black,11],
AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"}]
```

The problem here is that when I do:

```
Grid[{{b,b},{b,b}}]
```

axes labels overlap with numbers.

I checked many related questions and the best solution I found (for 2 dimensional plots) is to add

```
   Epilog -> {Inset["X", Scaled[{0.35, 0.38}]], Inset["Y",Scaled[{0.48,0.95}]]}
```

but this does not work for 3 dimensions.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I agree with @gpap. If that Q&A does not answer your question sufficiently, please provide additional details.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov this is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `Inset` and `Graphics` with `Epilog`. It gives you full control over label placement:

```
a = {{1, 1, 0.3}, {1, 2, 0.4}, {1, 3, 0.5}, {2, 1, 0.6}, {2, 2, 
    0.7}, {2, 3, 0.8}};

b = ListPlot3D[a, PlotLabel -> Style["A", 15], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 11]];
gr = Graphics[Inset[b, Center, Center, ImageScaled[.85]], 
  Epilog -> {Text["X", ImageScaled[{.4, .2}]], 
    Text["Y", ImageScaled[{.83, .3}]], 
    Text["Z", ImageScaled[{.05, 1/2}]]}]
```

> [image: plot]

```
Grid[{{gr, gr}, {gr, gr}}]
```

> [image: grid]

Answer (score 1):

While not optimal, you can convert the plots to images then put them into the grid. You may also consider trying the `BoxRatios` option to size your `ListPlot3D` such that the axis are the way you want them:

```
a={{1,1,0.3},{1,2,0.4},{1,3,0.5},{2,1,0.6},{2,2,0.7},{2,3,0.8}};

b=ListPlot3D[a,
PlotLabel->Style["A",15],
LabelStyle->Directive[Black,11],
AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"}, BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 3}]

bi=Image[b]

Grid[[{bi,bi},{bi,bi}]]
```